# itemize inside todo box

Tags: itemize, todonotes

```
\todo[inline]{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item aaaa
  \item bbbb
  \end{itemize}}
```

I have no problem to use `\todo` without using `itemize` inside. So what is the problems here?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code snippet to a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).